# Django group by substring on a field

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-model-field

I have a Django, PostgreSQL project.
I want to perform a group by on substring from a field.
Ex I have a model as `Model1` and its column as `name`. The value in the column can be:

```
ABC-w-JAIPUR-123
XYZ-x-JAIPUR-236
MNO-y-SURAT-23
DEF-q-SURAT-23
```

From the above values in `name` field, I want to group by second occurrence of `-` and ending with `-` in our case it would be: "JAIPUR", "SURAT"

Please let me know how to achieve this in Django.

UPDATE:
So far, I have tried:

```
Model1.objects.annotate(substring=Substr('name', F('name').index('-')+1, (F('name', output_field=CharField())[:F('name').rindex('-')]).index('-'))).values('substring').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

but this is giving error:

```
AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, an [**`F`** object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) is just an object to *reference* to a column. It is not the string value of that column, so you can not call `.index(…)` on this for example.

But more bad news is that its equivalent, [**`StrIndex`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#strindex) can not easily determine the second index, so we will have to fix that as well. We can however fix this by cutting the string twice, and thus work with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Left, Length, Right, StrIndex

hyp = Value('-')
drop1 = Right('name', Length('name') - StrIndex('name', hyp))
drop2 = Right(drop1, Length(drop1) - StrIndex(drop1, hyp))
drop3 = Left(drop2, StrIndex(drop2, hyp) - 1)
```

Then we thus can for example annotate with:

```
Model1.objects.annotate(foo=drop3)
```

The `drop1` will thus have dropped `ABC-`, the second `drop2` drops `w-` and finally `drop3` will drop all the rest of the groups, so it thus returns `JAIPUR` instead.

That being said, please don't make fields that somehow group data together. Store the different items in different columns. Combining is often a lot easier than extracting.

Comment: I will mark this as answered, but would like one more help from you. the "name" is in jsonfield like: col1 = {"name": "ABC-w-JAIPUR-123"}. Do you have any idea how we can perform same action but on a jsonfield key?

Comment: @Ridz: that's horrible code design: this means your database does not satisfy first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form Instead of trying to capture data out of a string, the columns should contain single units of data. So not `ABC-w-JAIPUR-123` combined, and definitely not in a JSON blob, but storing `ABC`, `w`, `JAIPUR` and `123` separately. The idea of first normal form is exactly to make filtering, aggregating and determining values easily. By making composite data, you thus end up writing inefficient queries that are errorprone.